# Wrapfig and Minipage not working in Beamer

Tags: minipage, wrapfig

Trying to employ the minipage and wrapfig packages to get itemized bullets to wrap around an image; however, the image is thrown to the next page by itself.  Is there anything in the code below that would cause this to fail?

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Fathead Minnow Toxicity (FMT)} 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Important as an indicator species biological model in aquatic toxicology studies, similar to the Canary in a coal mine. 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[t]{l}{0.3\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.13in,keepaspectratio]{fatheadminnow}
    \end{wrapfigure}
   \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Yes. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294964/121799) why it fails and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56228/121799) how to make things wrap in beamer.

Comment: is there a `minipage` package? or are you using the standard minipage environment? It is hard to see as you have not provided a usable example. A minipage around a wrapfig would presumably always stop the wrapfig environment working with or without the beamer class being used.

Comment: The cutwin package resolved the issue.   thx!

Comment: BTW, wrapfigure does not support a [t] option.  It was expecting a number there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, just adding text to the minipage fixed most of the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Fathead Minnow Toxicity (FMT)} 
\begin{itemize}
  \item Important as an indicator species biological model in aquatic toxicology studies, similar to the Canary in a coal mine. 
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \intextsep=0pt
    \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
       \includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.13in,keepaspectratio]{example-image}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    test text
   \end{minipage}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]